# Unable to find elements using latest Appium in Android 7 Emulator

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

I have written test automation scripts for Android using selenium and Appium with Java as coding language. The scripts are working perfectly fine on Android 6 Emulator. However, on Android 7 emulator, the driver launches the app but is unable to locate any element on the app.

Sample code:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

capabilities.setCapability("noReset", "true");

capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Nexus_5_API_24_Automation");

capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");

capabilities.setCapability("app","D:\\MyProject\\apk\\test-app-6.31.11.apk");

capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 0);

try {       
     driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);   
} catch (Exception e) {     
    Assert.fail("The app launched failed.");
 }

CommonUtils.waitInSeconds(10); // Custom method with Thread.sleep() method to wait for 10 secs


driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Device']")).click();


driver.closeApp();

driver.quit();
```

Where android.widget.TextView is the class name, ‘text’ attribute contains ’Device’ as a text.

When I run this, it fails at the driver.findElement step and throws NoSuchElementException.

The element with text 'Device' is a tab name and is visible and is clicked on Android 6 emulator.

For Android 6, I use Appium 1.4.13 GUI version.

For Android 7, I use Appium version 1.6.3 non UI version.

Appium client libs: java-client-4.1.2.jar

Please Note: I cannot use devices as they are not currently available in my organisation.

I am totally clueless as to what is causing this problem. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Launch Appium GUI Inspector and check if that element for sure has a text attribute. 
You can use Appium 1.5 GUI with inspector by providing emulator name in GUI and launching Appium 1.6.3 in CLI (so start appium 1.6.3, open appium GUI 1.5 and click inspector), it will work if You provide path to app and other 'staff' in settings.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! The element did have a text attribute but I found out that there was another problem. The text in the text attribute was automatically capitalised in Android 7.0 where as it was in small letters in Android 6.0. That was why it failed. Now the developer has agreed to change all the text to capital letters :)